# Writing SQL Query to find count of column with corresponding values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query for getting the count for how entries there are for a column that also has matching corresponding column values throughout the table.

to clarify, take for example this table of a person, a way to contact them, and the contact details

```
|PERSON_ID | CONTACT_TYPE | CONTACT_DETAIL|
| 1        | PHONE        | 123-4567      |
| 2        | FAX          | 234-5678      |
| 1        | FAX          | 345-6789      |
```

Now, lets say I want to find the number of people who have phone number X AND fax number y. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is. Post what you have tried so far and we'll assist you in correcting your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to self join the table, one for Phone and another for FAX.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t1.PERSON_ID)  --DISTINCT is to handle duplicates
FROM table_name t1, table_name t2
WHERE t1.PERSON_ID=t2.person_ID
AND t1.CONTACT_TYPE='PHONE'
AND t1.CONTACT_DETAIL=X --your search for PHONE
AND t2.CONTACT_TYPE='FAX'
AND t2.CONTACT_DETAIL=Y; --your search for FAX
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use aggregation to get the person ids:

```
select person_id
from t
where (contact_type, CONTACT_DETAIL) IN ( ('PHONE', X), ('FAX', Y) )
group by person_id
having count(*) = 2;  -- assumes no duplicates
```

To get the overall count, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select person_id
      from t
      where (contact_type, CONTACT_DETAIL) IN ( ('PHONE', X), ('FAX', Y) )
      group by person_id
      having count(*) = 2
     ) p;  -- assumes no duplicates
```

If a person could have two phone numbers or fax numbers, then use `count(distinct contact_type)` instead of `count(*)` in the above queries.

Comment: On the second query you could use DISTINCT.

Comment: How about the sittuation when a person have 2 different phone numbers? The request is phone number AND fax.